# Is it possible to use a dimmable LED GU10 bulb on a non-dimmable circuit?

Tags: lighting, led

Is it possible to use a dimmable LED GU10 bulb on a non-dimmable circuit?

I know you cannot use the opposite.

Comment: Think of it this way. What's the difference between a dimmer turned fully on and *no* dimmer?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is no problem doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply yes you can.
The reason for this is that with a non dimmable circuit the dimmable LED bulbs will either be on (100%) or off (0%) which both settings are absolutely fine for a dimmable bulb.
There will be no problems and no flickering.